# MySQL : using sum in( case when ) statement shows 0 as result

Tags: mysql

new to MySQL..so pls help me out with this basic code..
i have a query something like this...

```
select weekofyear(id_time),
(id),

@Tat1:=exp1,
@Tat2:=exp2,
@check1:=exp3,
@check2:=exp4, 
(case when @check2=0 then 
        (case when  (@Tat1>(@Tat2+30) or  (@check1=1 and (@Tat1>@Tat2+10)))  then 1  else 0 end)  
        else 
        (case when (@Tat1>(@Tat2+30) or  (@check1=1 and (@Tat1>@Tat2+20))) then 1 else 0 end) 
    end) as BO

from datb
where cid=18
and id_time between '2019-11-01 06:00:00' and '2019-11-25 06:00:00'
```

and it gives correct results as--[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPwG5.png)

however i want to use sum after case when statement so that I can get total values where BO=1 and group by week of year , so i made following changes-

```
select weekofyear(id_time),
count(id),

@Tat1:=exp1,
@Tat2:=exp2,
@check1:=exp3,
@check2:=exp4, 
sum(case when @check2=0 then 
        (case when  (@Tat1>(@Tat2+30) or  (@check1=1 and (@Tat1>@Tat2+10)))  then 1  else 0 end)  
        else 
        (case when (@Tat1>(@Tat2+30) or  (@check1=1 and (@Tat1>@Tat2+20))) then 1 else 0 end) 
    end) as BO

from datb
where cid=18
and id_time between '2019-11-01 06:00:00' and '2019-11-25 06:00:00'
group by weekofyear(id_time)
```

but it always returns 0 as output.
Output --here [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T50Xk.png)

Please help , I don't know what am I doing wrong here.

Thanx !

Comment: using MySQL user variables can be tricky .. *" The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.

In addition, the default result type of a variable is based on its type at the beginning of the statement. This may have unintended effects if a variable holds a value of one type at the beginning of a statement in which it is also assigned a new value of a different type. "*  [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)

Comment: .. besides that the `GROUP BY` also feels to be used wrong here with MySQL user variables... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, session variables can be unpredictable (especially when aggregation gets mixed in). That said, it doesn't look like you're using the session variables to carry over values from one row to the next (as is often done), but to just make aliases of sorts for calculations you don't want to repeat.

A better way to handle that is just through subqueries.

```
SELECT woy, id, Tat1, Tat2, check1, check2
    , CASE 
        WHEN check2=0 THEN (
            CASE 
            WHEN (Tat1>(Tat2+30) OR (check1=1 AND (Tat1>Tat2+10))) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
            END
        )
        ELSE (
            CASE WHEN (Tat1>(Tat2+30) OR (check1=1 AND (Tat1>Tat2+20))) THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
            END
        ) 
    END AS BO
FROM (
    SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(id_time) AS woy
        , id
        , exp1 AS Tat1
        , exp2 AS Tat2
        , exp3 AS check1
        , exp4 AS check2
    FROM datb
    WHERE cid=18
        AND id_time BETWEEN '2019-11-01 06:00:00' AND '2019-11-25 06:00:00'
) AS subQ
;
```

You can then tweak the above query for aggregation, or use it as a subquery for an aggregating outer query.